# Hidden field not been submitted (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made an application using codeigniter, and everything was working fine few day ago. But suddenly, yesterday, when I ran the application, I am getting error, when I am submitting data from the forms which contain enctype="multipart/form-data". Null data is received at the controller. When I remove enctype, than everything goes fine, but due to image upload, I have to keep enctype in some form tags.

```
    <form action="<?= site_url('nasty_v2/dashboard/uploadPaid?key=').$this->my_func->scpro_encrypt("betul"); ?>" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="portlet box purple-sharp">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i>Upload Payment Proof For 
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body flip-scroll" align="center">
                        <span style = "color : #b706d6;"><h2><strong>#<?= (120000+$orid); ?></strong></h2></span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" align="center" data-provides="fileinput">
                                <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="btn red btn-outline btn-file">
                                        <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
                                        <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
                                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="title"><input type="file" name="fileImg"> </span>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
                                </div><div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-upload"> Submit</i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="or_id" id="inputOr_id" class="form-control" value="<?= $or_id; ?>">                          
                    </div>
     </form>
```

I checked the HTTP request using Telerik Fiddler 2, and the found that form is successfully submitting data in request, but that data is not reaching controller.  What should be the issue?

Comment: did you do any change in the php.ini file?

Comment: No sir, I'm not making any changes in php.ini file

Comment: *everything was working fine few day ago. But suddenly...*: if you didn't change your code, there was most likely a server side change, like mysql or php version update (check with your hosting company, if you are on a shared server)

Comment: and my controller only contains var_dump($_POST); and I get this result array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

It may cause by the file upload. Try setting followings

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads',1000);
ini_set('post_max_size','5000M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','5000M');
//or php.ini file
```

Comment: I have follow your suggestion, but still got the same error and my controller only contains var_dump($_POST); and I get this result array(0) { }.